# Combine image/ icon with strings and display in TEXTVIEW

Tags: android

So here's my case, I store notes with checklist as following:

```
Shopping-list

[] Milk
[] Yogurt
[x] Egg
[x] Tomato
[x] Bacon
```

My notes were stored in SQLite, I can retrieve the exact data and display them in the main menu of my app. I want to convert those [] and [x] to an icon for better looking, [] indicate as unchecked while [x] means checked.

I tried to split each line of the list by using String.split
I tried code like this

```
String lines[] = note_content.split("\\r?\\n");
```

So right now my lines contain each of the check items separately, as following:

```
lines[0] = "[] Milk";
lines[1] = "[] Yogurt";
lines[2] = "[x] Egg";
lines[3] = "[x] Tomato";
lines[4] = "[x] Bacon";
```

I then tried to loop each of them and check whether it's checked or not using if else:

```
if(lines[i].subString(0,3).equals("[x]"){
        // means it's checked
}
```

But the problem is I have no idea how to add an icon on each check item and then display them as a string.

My final result would have something like following:

```
Shopping-list
[an empty box image] Milk
[an empty box image]Yogurt
[a check icon] Egg
[a check icon] Tomato
[a check icon] Bacon
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use the CheckBox view provided by Android?

Comment: because it is only for display purpose at the main screen of my application to display all notes, inside my adapter there's a line of code that do the job: holder.note_content.setText(note_content); , so I don't know how to implement checkbox view at this moment.

Comment: How are you displaying those strings? textView or ListView? If using textView try drawableLeft or drawableStart. If using ListView you probably need to modify your adapter

Comment: I'm using textview, how do I do that?